# Python Certbot module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, certbot, python-3.10

when I try to run `certbot` in my console on my Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS, I get following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from certbot import cert_manager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/cert_manager.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certbot import ocsp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/ocsp.py", line 25, in <module>
    from certbot.storage import RenewableCert # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/storage.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certbot import cli
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/cli.py", line 33, in <module>
    from certbot.plugins import disco as plugins_disco
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 183, in <module>
    class PluginsRegistry(collections.Mapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
```

I have already searched for a solution, but have not found one. Even posts that have the same error could not solve the problem for me. Strangely enough, it worked about two months ago.

I'm running Python 3.10.

Comment: importing from `collections` was deprecated and eventually removed in Python 3.10. The syntax in 3.10 is to import `collections.abc` instead.

Comment: you can see similar issue I opened for another pypi package [here](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues/173).

Comment: If I edit the file disco.py where the module `collections` is imported to `collections.abc` i get the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, I edited the file `/usr/bin/certbot` and changed `#!/usr/bin/python3` to: `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` because Certbot does not support Python 3.10 yet

Comment: are you *sure*? In their project page on pypi, they list 3.10 as one of their supported Python versions. https://pypi.org/project/certbot/#description

Comment: My meaning is, if you download the latest `certbot==1.22.0` and it breaks in 3.10, then their package description is erroneous. I would open up an issue on their GitHub project page in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```bash
sudo python3 -m venv /opt/certbot/
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install certbot certbot-nginx
sudo ln -s /opt/certbot/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbo
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove apt certbot and install snap certbot solved my python problem with certbot

```
sudo apt-get remove certbot

sudo snap install --classic certbot
```